# Rename tag [private-network-access] to [local-network-access]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

In light of [the WICG's recent decision](https://github.com/WICG/local-network-access/issues/91) to rename *Private Network Access* to *Local Network Access*, the [relevant tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/private-network-access) should be renamed accordingly.

Edit: The WICG has [seemingly reversed its decision to rename the feature](https://github.com/WICG/local-network-access/issues/91#issuecomment-1494704528).

Comment: Perhaps consider creating a new tag and then synonymize the old one to the new one

Comment: @TylerH It looks like only [four users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/private-network-access/topusers) have a score higher than 5 on that tag, so (AFAIK) creating a synonym is impossible. I think a moderator will need to do it.

Comment: @MichaelM. Yes I wasn't suggesting OP above be solely responsible for making that happen, sorry. Meant that we here on Meta could consider that action preferable so that "private-network-access" doesn't get re-created later on and so that tags that use it will still remain and make sense until such time as they get edited to refer to LNA instead of PNA, etc.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's no longer relevant (the WICG has since reversed its renaming decision).